# If input name is value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

This is my setup:

HTML

```
1. How are you?
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="1" value="2">Good
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="1" value="1">Okey
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="1" value="0">Bad
```

Javascript

```
 if ( name 1 has value 2)
  { do something }
 else if ( name 1 has value 1)
  { do something }
else if ( name 1 has value 0)
  { do something }
else
  { }
```

How do I make a if else statement out of name and value?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What can StackOverflow provide that can't be answered through a simple Google?

Comment: what you mean with generate? your sudo code is right..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var names = document.getElementsByName("1");

if (names[0].checked)
  { do something }
 else if (names[1].checked)
  { do something }
else if (names[2].checked)
  { do something }
else
  { }
```

Though it would seem simpler to just grab the checked one, and put its value in a `switch()` statement.

```
var chkd = document.querySelector(".calc:checked");

switch( chkd.value) {
   case 2: // ...
           break;
   case 1: // 
           break;
   default: // ...
}
```

However the `:checked` requires a modern browser, like IE9 or greater.

Answer (score 2):

The general premise behind an `if` statement is:

```
if ('statement to evaluate') {
    // Code to execute if above statement is true
} else if ('another statement')
    // Code executes if first statement was false, but second one is true
} else {
    // If both above statements are false, execute this code
}
```

Read more about if statments: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

More about what evaluates to true: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete example. The best part is - you don't need conditions at all. You can use the value itself to determine what callback to use. This method is called "property lookup".

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/oqoJOwU/2/edit)**

**Sample Markup:**

```
<form id="myForm">
  <h3>1. How are you?</h3>
  <input name="1" type="radio" value="2">
  <label>Good</label>

  <input name="1" type="radio" value="1">
  <label>Okay</label>

  <input name="1" type="radio" value="0">
  <label>Bad</label>

  <button disabled>Click me.</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#myForm input');

var submit = document.querySelector('#myForm button');

for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; ++i) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    submit.removeAttribute('disabled');
  });
}

var responses = [
  function() { //this is "responses[0]
    console.log('this handles value 1!');
  },
  function() { //this is "responses[1]
    console.log('this handles value 2!');
  },
  function() { //this is "responses[2]
    console.log('this handles value 3!');
  }
];

submit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var checked = document.querySelector("#myForm input:checked");
  var x = checked.value;
  responses[x](); //call the response function for this value
  e.preventDefault(); //prevent the form from submitting
});
```